markdown text, rather than formatted hyperlinks showing up in slackbot-generated slack messages
I have a python script that uses slackbot to automatically send out a message with a hyperlink to one or more images. I constructing the hyperlinks using markdown format (i.e. [Link text Here](Link URL here)). The hyperlinks aren't being displayed correctly.
In the script, this looks like the following:
payload = {"text": ("slackbot message text [Link text Here](https://google.com)")}
requests.post(webhook, json.dumps(payload))

I expected that the resulting message in slack would look like this:
slackbot message text Link text Here
The resulting message in slack displays the markdown text for the hyperlink with all the square brackets and parentheses rather than the hyperlink:
slackbot message text [Link text Here](https://google.com)

How do I get the slackbot messages to display cleanly formatted hyperlinks, rather than the markdown text of the hyperlinks?
